# How to include Acrobat Form Field Value in Submit Button URL Link

Tags: php, acrobat

I have an online Acrobat form that users fills out and select a Submit button.  I have the submit button defined to send the complete PDF file to a php program that simply attaches the file to an email (phpMailer) and sends it.

What I would like to do is send along with the static form name, the Customer Name field value from the Acrobat form.  So if the customer enters "John Doe" in the Customer_Name field, I want the following in the submit.

../submit_pdf_form.php?form=New_Patient&Customer_Name=John Doe

**Is this possible in Acrobat Pro X?  How to do it.**

thanks

-- PHP pgm source code highlights --

```
<?php
// what form are we sending
if (isset($_GET['form']))    { $form_type = $_GET['form']; }
//////////////////////////////////////////////////
//// this is the catching of the PDF
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
if(!isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA)) 
{
    echo "The Application could not be sent. Please save the PDF and email it manually.";
    exit;
}
//////////////////////////////////////////
// Create PDF file with the filled data
//////////////////////////////////////////
$semi_rand = $form_type . time();
$pdf = $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA;
$file = $semi_rand . ".pdf"; 
$handle = fopen($file, 'w+');
fwrite($handle, $pdf);   
fclose($handle);
/////////////////////////////////////////
require_once("\phpMailer\class.phpmailer.php");
...
set up mail
...
if(!$mail->AddAttachment($file))
    {
        echo "There was a problem attaching the pdf.";
        echo $mailer->ErrorInfo;
    }
 if(!$mail->Send()) {
    $error = "Error sending Email ".$mail->ErrorInfo; 
        echo $error; }
```

Answer (score 1):

So I finally figured out how to get information from an adobe online form.

**ACROBAT:**

In Acrobat create a button, under actions select Trigger on "Mouse Down", select Action "Run a JavaScript", click on "Add".  On the popped up window add something like the follow to get your form fields and submit the form to another program to email via phpmailer.  This sends the entire PDF file to your program.

```
var name = getField("Shipper Name").valueAsString;  // get name field
name = name.replace(/(^[\s]+|[\s]+$)/g, '');        // trim spaces 
name = name.replace("'", "\\'");                    // change O'Neil to O\'Neil 
name = "'"+name+"'";
var email = getField("Shipper Email").valueAsString; // get email address
email = email.replace(/(^[\s]+|[\s]+$)/g, '');      // trim spaces from front and end
console.println("Your Email is Being sent to you and Dr. xxxxxx");
this.submitForm({
cURL: "../submit_pdf_form.php?form=New_Patient_Form&name="+name+"&email="+email,
cSubmitAs: "PDF"                                   // select form type PDF, FDF
```

});

See the link below for additional help on the Acrobat button definition

http://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/WCAG20-TECHS/PDF15.html

**PHP**
Then you can pull the info into a PHP program to send like the following:

```
<?php
include("class.phpmailer.php");        
// what form are we sending
$form_type = "";
$cust_name = "";
$cust_email = "";
if (isset($_GET['form']))  { $form_type = $_GET['form']; }
if (isset($_GET['name']))  { $cust_name = $_GET['name']; 
                           $temp = "\'";
                           $cust_name = str_replace($temp, "'", $cust_name);
                       }
if (isset($_GET['email'])) { $cust_email = $_GET['email']; }
//////////////////////////////////////////////////
//// this is the catching of the PDF
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
if(!isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA)) 
{
    echo "The Application could not be sent. Please save the PDF and email it manually.";
    exit;
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Create PDF file with the filled data
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
$semi_rand = $form_type . "-" . date("s", time());
$pdf = $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA;
$file = $semi_rand . ".pdf"; 
$handle = fopen($file, 'w+');
fwrite($handle, $pdf);   
fclose($handle);
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
//// this is the Emailing of the PDF
/////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
$mail_subject = "Patient Web Forms: " . $form_type;
$mail_message = "Patient submitted webform: \n" . $form_type . "\n Form from " . $cust_name . "\n Patient email: " . $cust_email;
$mail_from = "someone@comapny.com";
$mail_from_name = "Web Forms";
$mail_host = "smtp.company.net";
$username = "johndoe";
$password = "password"; 
$mail_to = "johndoe@company.com";                  // ---- use comma as separators
// --- look for localhost vs production ----
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "localhost")             // -- test mode  ?
{
    $mail_to = "johndoe@testcom.com";
}
else
{
    $mail_to = "johndoe@company.com";
}
$message = "";

$mail = new PHPmailer(true);  // create a new object  (true = displays error messages) 
$mail->IsSMTP();          // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;         // debugging: 0 = off, 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
// $mail->SMTPAuth = true;    // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->Host = $mail_host;
$mail->Username = $username;  
$mail->Password = $password;           
$mail->SetFrom($mail_from, $mail_from_name);
$mail->Subject = $mail_subject;
$mail->Body = $mail_message;
$mail->AddAddress($mail_to);

if(!$mail->AddAttachment($file))
{
    $message = "There was a problem attaching the pdf.";
    echo "There was a problem attaching the pdf.";
    echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
    die;
}

if(!$mail->Send()) {
    $message = "Error sending Email ".$mail->ErrorInfo; 
} 
else 
{
    $message = "Form emailed to Dr Pearson's office";
}

$mail->ClearAddresses();
$mail->ClearAttachments();
unlink($file);              // delete the temporary pdf file then redirect to the success page
header("location: patients.php?msg=$message");

unlink($file);  //doubley make sure the temp pdf gets deleted
?>
```